# JSF 1.2 Application.getMessageBundle() returns null

Tags: jsf, resourcebundle

I'm using **Spring 2.5** with **JSF 1.2**, on **Tomcat 6.0.13**.

In one part of code, I'm trying to load *ResourceBundle* by using following approach:

```
ResourceBundle.getBundle(context.getApplication().getMessageBundle(), Locale.EN);
```

The problem is that *getMessageBundle()* method returns **null**. This used to work with **JSF 1.1**. 
Does anybody have idea what could be the problem?

For now I'm going to hardcode bundle name, but I would prefer if all my configuration data will be placed inside *faces-config*.

Resource bundle is set as following:

```
    <application>
        <locale-config>
            <default-locale>en</default-locale>
        </locale-config>
        <resource-bundle>
            <base-name>org.mysite.MessageBundle</base-name>
            <var>msgs</var>
        </resource-bundle>
    </application>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getMessageBundle()` returns the value of `<message-bundle>` entry in `faces-config.xml`, not the `<resource-bundle>` entry.

Its value is actually not avaliable by the JSF 1.2 API. You have to specify it yourself.

```
ResourceBundle bundle = context.getApplication().getResourceBundle(context, "org.mysite.MessageBundle");
```

The `<message-bundle>` is for validation/conversion messages. Probably you've *actually* used this in JSF 1.1.

Comment: Ok, didn't know this functionality is missing ins JSF 1.2. Thanx a lot!

Comment: It's also not present in other versions. I'd expect it to be somewhere in 2.0, but there is also not. You must have been confusing resourcebundles (for content) with messagebundles (for facesmessages).

Answer (score 3):

IgorB,

You may be able to use resource injection to have JSF provide your managed bean with the correct ResourceBundle. This would remove the need to hard-code anything in your Java source and keep the association nicely centralized.

Start by defining a managed property on your backing bean. In the JSF configuration, set the managed property's value to an EL expression that references your resource bundle.

I've done something like the following using Tomcat 6. The only caveat is that you can't access this value from your backing bean's constructor, since JSF will not yet have initialized it. Use `@PostConstruct` on an initialization method if the value is needed early in the bean's lifecycle.

```
<managed-bean>
  ...
  <managed-property>
    <property-name>messages</property-name>
    <property-class>java.util.ResourceBundle</property-class>
    <value>#{msg}</value>
  </managed-property>
  ...
</managed-bean>

<application>
  ...
  <resource-bundle>
    <base-name>application_messages</base-name>
    <var>msg</var>
  </resource-bundle>
  ...
</application>
```